# SQL how to group

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

Say I have a table as follows

```
Waiter          Complaints
Tim                Slow
John               Rude
Mike               Dumb
Tim                Asleep
Tim                Charge too much
Mike               Lazy
```

How do create a table where the waiters are ordered by the most number of complaints, but the complaints also show? Ex below

```
Waiter          Complaints
Tim                Slow
Tim                Asleep
Tim                Charge too much
Mike               Lazy
Mike               Dumb
John               Rude
```

Comment: Do you want to create a table or just query the table for that result set?

Comment: Just join the table to itself...

Answer (score 3):

Just count the number of complaints per waiter and join that to your table:

```
select t1.waiter,t1.complaints
from table t1
inner join(
  select waiter,count(1) as num_complaints
  from table
  group by waiter
)t2
on(t1.waiter = t2.waiter)
order by t2.num_complaints desc,t1.waiter,t1.complaints;
```

Comment: Downvoter: Care to explain?

Comment: Here is a fiddle with a demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/49240/1

Answer (score 1):

This being MySQL, you can put the complaints on a single row, using `group_concat()`:

```
select waiter, group_concat(complaints)
from t
group by waiter
order by count(*) desc
```

This isn't exactly the format that you have in the question.  It provides an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want a group by, you want Order By

```
select Waiter, Complaints
from Service
order by Waiter desc
```

Comment: Except the OP doesn't really want it ordered by the waiter - they want it by the number of complaints the waiter has.

Answer (score -1):

This would give you the waiter, the complaints, and the count of each type of complaint for each waiter:

```
SELECT waiter, complaints, COUNT(complaints) AS `complaint_count`
FROM table
GROUP BY waiter, complaints
ORDER BY `complaint_count` DESC
```

Note that this won't order the waiters together but rather the top waiter-complaint combinations, so you could have something like:

```
Mike    Dumb    5
Tim     Lazy    3
Mike    Rude    2
Tim     Rude    1
```

You can order by waiter first as well by changing last line to:

```
ORDER BY waiter ASC, `complaint_count` DESC
```

This might give something like:

```
Mike    Dumb    5
Mike    Rude    2
Tim     Lazy    3
Tim     Rude    1
```

Answer (score -1):

You simply want to sort (ORDER BY WAITER) not group (edit: to produce the listing you say you want).